# Custom actions cannot be specified in projects which are not created using custom category

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I'm trying to migrate an old Dialogflow action to Actions Builder, using the migration tool in the Actions Console.

When I press "Migrate" button, the console error message pops up with a text:

"*Custom actions cannot be specified in projects which are not created using custom category.*"

[Actions Console Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nojhh.png)

My project is "News & magazines" category.

Searching for solution I've found only Reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/m5d6lp/custom_actions_cannot_be_specified_in_projects/).
Unfortunately, no solution offered.

Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Has resolved by itself.
But now I get another error after "Enabling test..." message in the simulator: "Invalid intent name '8181e2e9-3d9f-428d-b220-3b6616de7151"
[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gO0zVWkV3u0JHldEQFCX-U7pk5CP2sts/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: OK that one resolved too.